# How do I float div's to the bottom of a page?

Tags: html, css

Like the question says, I can't float anything to the bottom... I tried float:absolute and it showed that. There's supposed to be 5 different boxes, but it only shows one of them. This is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#one,#two,#three,#four,#five {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  height:50%;
  width:20%;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
}
div {
    margin:-2px;
    padding:-2px;
}
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#one {
  background-color: blue;
}
#two {
  background-color: green;
}
#three {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#four {
  background-color: orange;
}
#five {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">

</div>

<div id="two">

</div>

<div id="three">

</div>

<div id="four">
</div>

<div id="five">
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: They are stacking on top of each other...

Comment: Maybe you should read up on what float actually does? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float — `bottom` and `absolute` are not values it accepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code's not working because you've essentially set all 5 boxes to stack on top of each other by having absolute positioning, 0 margin and left set to 0 for all 5 boxes, so everything takes the same positioning on the bottom left corner of the screen. If you remove right:0 and add an individual left property for each box, you should be able to have all 5 boxes in a neat row at the bottom, like so:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#one,#two,#three,#four,#five {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  height:50%;
  width:20%;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
}
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#one {
  background-color: blue;
  left:0;
}
#two {
  background-color: green;
  left:20%;
}
#three {
  background-color: yellow;
  left:40%;
}
#four {
  background-color: orange;
  left:60%;
}
#five {
  background-color: red;
  left:80%;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hq2hv1pw/

Also on a side note, I'd combine the selector with a class for the CSS style that has 5 IDs haha.
Hope this helps you out

Comment: Works, thanks :D Yeah, I really should make a class instead XD I feel stupid

Comment: Maybe you want those divs to be really at bottom , for that I would change position absolute to fixed

Comment: @Matthew it depends on whether he/she/they want the divs to be at the bottom of the document or at the bottom of the viewport; in this context I'm guessing document. But if the divs are meant to be at the bottom of the page, then, yeah position:fixed; would be the one to use.